# Is it possible to see content of php file (In case I see list of php files available on server)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Let's say I can see list of files available on server. check the attached screens shot. Any way to check the file content as well? (assume listing from live site)

[image]

Comment: No not if you don't have read/write access. In other words, a user can't see the content. Only site admin can.

Comment: what server are you using?

Comment: where to define read/write access and if access is not configured what is the default behaviour? I am using apache server.

Comment: you would have to either rename the file (to .phps, or .txt extension) or execute another php file whose job would be to display the file you want to open.

Comment: You can try right click on it and 'Download as...'

Comment: @ElvisPlesky didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for the method I used to answer this question. I received errors about code indent by 4 spaces but my answer was well formed however I was not able to post my answer due to bugs in the Stack Overflow system.. I added a screenshot to this answer with my original answer included (Screenshot from answer example) and hope my answer is still useful. I didn't contact Stack Overflow staff as this is a known issue.. see also [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298225/question-gets-error-please-indent-all-code-by-4-spaces) and others wich are about similar issues.

[image: error message]

### My answer (Screenshot / Screencapture)

[image]

As I were not able to put the code in separated code blocks I put them all in 1 code block only, please see the screenshot above to understand the numbers, **Code 1** is the first code block in the image, **code 2** is the second code you'll find on the screenshot etc... **The screenshot has been edited, I added code block numbers to the picture..**

```
/** Code 1 **/

<?php // This can be used in a file that should be included to an other file
if(!defined('NO_CONTENT_AVAILABLE')) {
die('This file cannot be accessed directly!<br /><br />Something went wrong and the content is out for a walk...'); /** Do not change it's a text for users who visit this document... **/
}
/** Your content for tthe file below this line **/
?>

/** Code 2 **/

 <?php
 define('NO_CONTENT_AVAILABLE',1); /** You'll need this line on top OR above the line where you'll use the file that require NO_CONTENT_AVAILABLE to be defined **/
 include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/to/your/file.php'; /** the file that require NO_CONTENT_AVAILABLE to be defined **/
 ?>

/** Code 3 **/

Options -Indexes

/** Code 4 **/

<RequireAll>
    Require ip 178.221.255.121 2a02:a430:fe83:1:ca:4240:2e0:16 192.168.150.254
</RequireAll>
```

All other IP adresses cannot open the directory and will receive status code 403 FORBIDDEN or other status depending on your configuration

> The files should be accessible by your visitors but you do not need the listings as the files should not be accessed directly. This said there are only two options in my answer that fit your needs:

1. Update all files where it's needed with the php code above that will deny direct access, to add `define` and`defined`to all of your files will be a lot of work as you need to edit a lot of files...
2. add `Options -Indexes` to your `.htaccess` file
3. Use both of the above options wich is what I do on custom coded websites. even if you don't show indexes, the files still can be accessible in any webbrowser and that's why you might want to use both of the above options ...

I hope I was able to offer the information you need and that this answer will bring you into the right direction.

Comment: Why downvote without comment? What is wrong with this answer?

Comment: I think I am aware of all this stuff. My question is not - how to restrict or unrestrict users. My question is if my live site shows the listing of files as the attached image. Will it be possible for someone to see the code of these php files? its obvious I am not providing any restrictions in .htaccess file, that is the reason files are getting listed on browser. but still can someone look into my php code?   I understand php code runs at server side but still is there any possibility end users can check my php code by any means?

Comment: No You cannot view source of the php code but you can view the sourse of the output of the php files. If anything isn't properly defined in your php code it can cause errors and offer them information you might want to keep private so No they cannot view PHP source but the files should not show warnings or notices such as full server path etc for security reasons that's why I wrote the `define` and `defined` php code for you as this will protect you from showing critical information to your users and will show the real output when included where it's allowed by `define`